# Notification не осуществляет переход в Activity по нажатию

Tags: java, android, уведомления, android-notification

Есть AlarmManager, устанавливает событие на 9 утра каждого дня. Когда он срабатывает, отображается уведомление, по нажатию на которое должно открываться активити. Уведомление отображается, а Activity по нажатию не открывается.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notify))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notifytext));
    Intent goToAppIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(goToAppIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    long mills = 300L;
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    try{
        notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
        vibrator.vibrate(mills);}
    catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if(pref.getBoolean("notific", true)){
        restartNotify(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы `PendingIntent` создаёте с интентом ресивера, а не с тем, который должен запускать вашу активити. Т.е. надо так:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        goToAppIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );
```

Comment: Всё равно не работает...

Comment: См. обновленный ответ